# Docker node js container wont run

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

[My page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzCkW.jpg)
I want to make my API file dockerize but when I try to run my image its closes instantly
I'm thinking my docker file is wrong but I don't know how I fix

My docker file:

```
FROM node:15
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY ./api /usr/src/app
COPY .env /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and when I run to image closes instantly

Docker log

```
> malice-api@1.0.0 start
> node ./api/index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/api/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 7.7.6 -> 7.14.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.14.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.14.0` to update!
npm notice

> malice-api@1.0.0 start
> node ./api/index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/api/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: How are you running the container?  If you `docker run --rm -it your-image sh`, you'll get an interactive shell in a new container based on the image; are all the files where you expect them to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

> If `<src>` is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata.The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.

So, try to change the second `copy` instruction to

```
COPY api /usr/src/app/api
```